# How do I stop the help/search feature from EVER auto-calling people? iPod Touch, iOS 9.2

Tags: ipod-touch, settings, facetime, siri

**My real concern is the the AUTOMATIC ability of my device to call out to people (FaceTime) without ANY confirmation from me. Not just FaceTime, but anything similar as well (texting/email).**
All the results I've found only solve the calling (phone) problem while the device is locked (asleep or set to lock screen). I just got this device and this scary thing happened: 
1. I pressed the hold button down too long by accident
2. Search came up with sound recording on
3. A friend, trying to help, said "turn off applications", thinking this would bring us to a help result about how to turn off an app running in the background (I didn't know how because I was used to an older iOS).
4. The ipod IMMEDIATELY begain FaceTime calling my boss's boss! Late at night!

I would never want my iPod to attempt to do send ANYTHING or connect to something, (especially FaceTime!), without my direct approval. (And horrible voice interpretation is NOT direct approval in my book. Her name sounds NOTHING like "turn off applications".) **Opening an app is okay, but doing something that can't be undone is not. How can I ensure that nothing like this will happen again?** 
-Turn off the help's "auto-do it" ability? (I'd be okay with turning off help altogether if that was needed, but that seems like overkill.) Can it decide to write and send texts/messages/emails for me? Make Facebook posts? Without even an "approve" button required? This is all very creepy.  
-Turn off the voice activation feature completely? I thought it could be good for searching and faster typing. But I imagined speaking a sentence, fixing the errors and pressing a send button myself. Not having to fear that the device will "send" data for me. If I turn off voice, could typing something into the search do the same "auto send"? Because that is not good either.
-Turn off something in FaceTime?  It should only call someone if I open the app and tell it to do that. I wouldn't ever want it to call someone without a definite YES pressed. I haven't found such a setting.

Everything I've found talks about telling a phone to not auto-call when the screen is locked. My device is not a phone and some of the settings I've read about simply aren't on my device (iPod Touch), or at least not in the place they say. Also, I need a solution that works all the time, not just when the device is locked. I'm not fully aware of which apps could be involved and what the device can and can't do by itself in this matter, so I might not be searching for the right things. I've read that the problem was not Siri, but I've also read something implying that even when you turn Siri off, she can still be used when you're using search/help.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're using. Are you using Siri or the iOS 9 "Smart Search"?

Comment: I'm really not sure. Like I said, Siri is turned off. It happened when you hold down the home button for a prolonged period. So I assume it's "smart search", but it's not like it labels itself. It only said "search", but was clearly recording audio, which is what prompted the person next to me to try talking to it.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious things you can change are several:

1. Turn off Siri - that is a sledge hammer to make sure you never do things by voice.
2. Turn off FaceTime - that also is a sledge hammer in that you can't use FaceTime normally.
3. Turn off the device or move it a) out of voice range if you allow "Hey Siri" b) out of arm range if you keep both 1 and 2 on from above.

Comment: Wow.
1. As I already said - Siri was ALREADY OFF.
2. I had not even signed in to Facetime yet. When I went to use Facetime immediately afterword. it wouldn't let me until I signed in specifically in that app. (Obviously, the device already knew my FaceTime info since I had already signed into the device itself with my Apple ID.) But, as I said, I don't want the search feature doing anything else either, such as texting or composing and sending an email. Which is why I would only want "Turn off Facetime" if that's the ONLY solution.
3. That is the worst suggestion. Please take this seriously.

Comment: I listed the things you can change, Amy. You're not missing anything, so perhaps lobby Apple to change their design in iOS 10?